# VSCode icon in task bar is blank

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is how Vscode appear in task bar , I don't know why

[image]

Comment: That's funny tho, try restarting the pc or re-installing the vscode.

Answer (score 47):

Open Windows Explorer, go to `%userprofile%\AppData\Local`, delete `IconCache.db`. (This file is hidden, so it you don't see it, you will need to adjust your Windows Explorer settings to show hidden files.)

Open Task Manager, go to Processes tab, highlight `explorer.exe`, and click End Process. Your desktop will "disappear."

Still in Task Manger, select File > New Task (Run...), type `explorer.exe`, and click OK. Your desktop should reappear, with the previously missing icons.

Comment: This is the only suggestion that worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Word of warning: it closed most of the applications I had running.

Answer (score 8):

This just happened to me, and after a bit of fiddling around I managed to fix it.

1. Open VS Code
2. Right-click on the open VsCode icon that is blank in your task bar.
3. Click the button that says Microsoft Visual Studio Code
4. Right-click again, and click pin to task bar.
5. Voila

Comment: I tried it and you're right, it does change it. But clicking it again, it changes back to an empty file icon. Strange.

Comment: I tried these solution but it seems to work temporarily. I found this github issue that provides a different fix. That did it for me. Here is the link https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34106#issuecomment-336600688

Answer (score 6):

I used another method that worked pretty well

1.Open VS Code 
2.Right-click on the open VsCode icon that is blank in your task bar.
3.Right-click the button that says Visual Studio Code, click on properties.
4.On the Shortcut tab, click on Change Icon...
5.Select the VsCode Icon and press Apply.

And that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Windows 11.

- Open VScode, the blank icon is displayed on the taskbar.
- Right click on the taskbar icon and Pin it.
- Now right click again but now to Unpin it. The icon should now be visible.

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced like that

1. run  as administrator vs code
2. richt click vs code on task bar and then select vs code, a confirmation will appear to delete the short cut, select yes
3. select pin to taskbar
4. right click and then select unpin to task bar
5. holla this is work for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using a portable version and I just updated it and the folder location was different than the last one. I also deleted the older version of the VS Code which was installed using the installer.

[image: Vs Code Open Menue]

**Above image is after I resolve the issues**

Upon clicking the `Visual Studio Code` button it says that the shortcut is missing its target.
1). I pinned that to my taskbar.
2). Clicked on that shortcut and Windows told me to delete it since the target is missing.
3). And opened the VS Code regularly as I do normally from my Unity Editor.

**Note. I'm using VS Code with Unity so your milage may vary.**

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing this after I uninstalled VS Code installed with the system installer to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code`, and re-installed it with the user installer.

All I had to do was:

1. unpin VS Code from the task bar (this shortcut points to the old non-existent installation)
2. start VS Code from the start menu (the correct icon will now be shown)
3. pin VS code back to the task bar

Answer (score 0):

For me after killing VS Code in task manager and then again opening it using window key helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue.

I moved the file location the original shortcut went to then created a new shortcut for the new destination. The shortcut on the desktop had the correct icon, but the one on the task bar did not. when I pined it to the task bar, then unpinned it, the vscode logo showed up on the task bar. When I pined it again, it went back to the empty page logo. When I closed it and opened it again, it went back to the empty page logo.

I tried right clicking on the taskbar logo then right clicking on the button the said Visual Studio Code, as directed in one of the previous posts, and it kept giving me an error message. Turns out the task bar logo was still trying to load the old shortcut for some reason, even though I was opening it from the new shortcut. It gave me an option to delete the old shortcut again and once I did that the logo popped right up.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

- first search VSC in Search Box, then open file location
- after that, right click on the VSC shortcut, choose Properties.
- click on "Change Icon", select the correct VSC icon
- Apply -> OK

Finally, I run the VSC shortcut as administrator.

The blank icon disappeared